# if else statement python using plot parameters in function

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, if-statement, plot, time-series

I have an if else statement in my function that is not wokring the way i want it to. Mind you I am still learning python and all things programming.

I have a function to define a plot. Idea is to create a large python repo for data analysis. EDIT: i added a working make shift dataframe for you to try

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
#import numpy as np
#import os
#import dir_config as dcfg
#import data_config as datacfg
import matplotlib.dates as md
#import cartopy.crs as ccrs

data = {'dates': [20200901,20200902,20200903,20200904,20200905,20200906,20200907,20200908,20200909,20200910],
        'depth': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
        'cond': [30.1,30.2,30.3,30.6,31,31.1,31.0,31.4,31.1,30.9]
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['dates', 'depth', 'cond'])
df['pd_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'])
 

def ctd_plots_timeseries(time=[],cond=[], sal =[], temp=[], depth=[], density=[]):
    #-----------
    # CONDUCTIVITY PLOT
    #-----------
    
    if cond == []:
        print("there is no data for cond")
        pass
    else:
        plt.scatter(time,depth,s=15,c=cond,marker='o', edgecolor='none')
        plt.show()

    #-----------
    # SALINITY (PSU) PLOT: I do not want this to plot at all due to its parameter being 'empty' in the function when called
    #-----------
    if sal == []:
        print('there is no salinity data')
        pass
    else:
        plt.scatter(time,depth,s=15,c=sal,marker='o', edgecolor='none')
        plt.show()


ctd_plots_timeseries(depth = df['depth'], time = df['pd_datetime'], cond = df['cond'])
```

The idea here is that if there is no data in the cond value, do `pass` to not show the plot.
However ever time I run this, the plot shows, even thought there is no data for it.

When i call the function i put in `plot_timeseries(time=time_data, depth=depth_data temp=temp_data)`

my aim is for only the temp data in this example to show, not a cond graph with no variables.

what i have tried is

```
if cond != []:
        plotting code
        plt.show()
else:
        print('there is no cond data')
        pass
```

and

```
plotting code
if cond == []:
    print('no cond data')
    pass
else:
    plt.show()
```

to no avail.

note that there are 4 other plots in this function i would like to do the same thing. thanks for any insight this community can give me.

UPDATE:
I changed the conditions in the function to `def ctd_plots_timeseries(time=0,cond=0, sal =0, temp=0, depth=0, density=0):`
and then changed conditional statement to

```
if cond != 0:
    graphing code
else:
    print('no data here')
```

i get the following error:
`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: @DavidG, i will edit the original post now

Comment: Thanks. `cond` is a pandas series. So you can use `if cond.empty:`

Comment: I tried this and gave me an Attribute error. I dont think python knows that these variables are panda df yet, maybe, since in my repo i grab them from another python file.

Answer (score 1):

I've simplified it. Try that:

```
def plots_timeseries(cond = []): # Single argument for clarity
    if not cond:
        print('there is no cond value')
    else:
        print('There is cond')

plots_timeseries()
# there is no cond value
```

Comment: i tried this, i get the following error: ```ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().```

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out a working solution.

```
if len(cond) == 0:
   print('there is no cond data')
else:
   plt.scatter(time,depth,s=15,c=cond)
   plt.show()
```

Lots of time and effort was put in to trying to solve this, and this solution was a test, after a good night sleep. Thanks for all the help. hope this helps someone else if that have a similar issue